# Sharepoint edit view - folders setting in Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

In my Sharepoint project I have a Document Library with multiple views. For a certain view, I want to set in its Folders settings, that the view must be shown "In all folders". 
This can easily be set in the browser, but I need to do it in Designer 2010.

The reason for this, is that I need to also set some advanced customised sorting options in Designer (for an XsltListViewWebpart that resides in the aspx of this view), and if I use both environments for setting things, Designer and browser, then setting one reverts the other.

How can I set Show this view - "In all folders", but in Designer instead of directly in browser?

Thank you for your suggestions. Please let me know if the description of the issue is not clear.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have group with above permissions, you must create a custom permission level with your requirement.

Once Permission level is created,

Create a group with the custom permission level & add users to that group.

more info here: http://www.techyv.com/questions/how-do-i-createedit-view-sharepoint

Comment: To avoid any confusion please emember to explicitly mention when you link to your own blog